# Spotfire 7 -> How to apply custom sort order on a list object using Iron Python

Tags: sorting, ironpython, spotfire

Spotfire 7 -> How to apply a custom sort order on a list object using Iron Python in Spotfire 7? I am using document.properties["Columns"] list to populate the columns of the cross table at the run time. I would like to apply the custom sort order on this list before I assign the list values to the columns of the cross table visualization

Comment: https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/sorting.html <<<>>>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/612995/6167855 <<<>>>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178612/datatable-sorting-in-iron-python

Answer (score 1):

Please see this reference:

- https://community.tibco.com/wiki/use-ironpython-set-custom-sort-order-tibco-spotfirer

Here is an example which creates a reverse custom sort order:

```
from System.Reflection import Assembly 
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Collections import *
from System.Runtime.Serialization import ISerializable
from System.Collections import IComparer
from System.Collections.Generic import IComparer

values = Document.Data.Tables['MY_DATA_TABLE'].Columns['DATE'].RowValues.GetEnumerator()
myValues = []
for val in values:
                myValues.Add(val.ValidValue)
                myValues.sort(reverse=True)
Document.Data.Tables['MY_DATA_TABLE'].Columns['DATE'].Properties.SetCustomSortOrder(myValues)
```